# pfctl divert-socket in mac os?

Tags: macos, sockets, openbsd, pf, ipfw

I'm messing with divert sockets in OSX, and in order to capture any socket, I first need to set up a firewall redirection (divertion if you will):

```
ipfw add divert 3282 tcp from any to any
```

Something like that, however "ipfw" is deprecated, and instead mac uses PF(5), so the command should be:

```
pass out on en0 inet proto tcp to port 80 divert-packet port 9090
```

This however, when loaded with `pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` returns a syntax error.

Here are docs stating that the divert-packet option really exist: https://man.openbsd.org/pf.conf.5#divert-packet_port

No idea why I get the syntax error. please help? how can I enable this divert-packet rule?

Answer (score 4):

> Here are docs stating that the divert-packet option really exist:

the docs you're citing are written for *OpenBSD*.

Meanwhile Pf was originally written for OpenBSD indeed and Apple had it ported for MacOS it [does not mean](https://etcinsider.com/blog/2016/02/28/openbsd-pf-for-mac-os-x-is-mostly-outdated/) they're updating it.